# Firebase permission denied while trying to read from db but I can write(Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Edit: I updated retrieveData(). Now my method displays the correct amount of elements in my db in onChildAdded() but gets an error while I try to assign Info post to postSnapshot.getValue(Info.class). Here is my Info class without setters,getters etc

```
  public Info(String question,String answer,String a,String b,String c,String d){
        this.question=question;
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
        this.d=d;
        this.answer=answer;
    }
    public Info(){

    }
}





public void retrieveData(){
                Log.e("burdayım sa","saaaaaaaaaaa");
                databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Log.e("Count " ,""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Info post = postSnapshot.getValue(Info.class);
                            Log.e("Get Data", post.getQuestion());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Log.e("Count " ,""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Info post = postSnapshot.getValue(Info.class);
                            Log.e("Get Data", post.getQuestion());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.e("The read failed: " ,databaseError.getMessage());
                    }

        });
    }
  @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**This is the error :  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.sahilliolu.rqagame.Info**

---

So, this is my code to receive the data. I handle the authentication in the previous activity and I can write things to my DB from this activity( I do not use firebase object for that) but when I try to get an object it gives me permission denied. How can I solve this? Here is how I write to db.

```
 firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class));
        }
        FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions");



Info info=new Info(question,answer,a,b,c,d);
                newDatabaseReference=databaseReference.push();
                newDatabaseReference.setValue(info);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your question is created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: What do your Firebase rules look like?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: I am new to firebase so it is probably default. I think I fail because my firebase variable with which I try to read from DB does not have authorization.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what your database structure looks like?

Comment: Please send the snapshot of your firebase account,

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/DP93Rv.png

Answer (score 0):

You are using both the legacy SDK and the new SDK:

```
// legacy
firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
firebase=new Firebase("https://mylink");

// new
FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions");
```

This is not good practice and is likely the source of the problem.

You should use the new SDK exclusively.  Remove this line from your build dependencies and update your code:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.X.X'
```

The [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) is helpful.

Comment: so I need to change my retrieve with databaseReferece childListeners?

Comment: That would be safest.  It's easy.  See the Upgrade Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to wrong node which not consists your required variable and consists only one string(may be question only)